# GoLang JSON Marshal omitempty with non-simple types - possible to avoid pointers?

Tags: json, pointers, go

Code below is the explanation. The only way I can get omitempty to work with non-simple types is to make that type a pointer.

Is there an alternative solution to this by not using pointers?

CODE NOT WORKING:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar Bar `json:"bar,omitempty"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Baz string `json:"baz"`
}

func main() {

    foo := Foo{}

    jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(foo)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", jsonBytes)
}
```

OUTPUT: `{"bar":{"baz":""}}`

CODE WORKING, BUT NOT WHAT I WANT:

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar *Bar `json:"bar,omitempty"`
}

type Bar struct {
    Baz string `json:"baz"`
}

func main() {

    foo := Foo{}

    jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(foo)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", jsonBytes)
}
```

OUTPUT: `{}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an alternative solution to this by not using pointers?

No.